# Is it possible to automate macOS applications using pywinauto?

Tags: python, macos, pywinauto

I have written pywinauto scripts for Windows automation.

Can we run the same scripts on macOS?

Comment: Even when we can, the scripts will not be directly portable because UI hierarchy, control types and other things may have big difference between OSs. Even for the same cross-platform app.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps eventually, but probably not right now. The developers of pywinauto plan to add macOS support, but it is still in early stages. You can follow this issue on pywinauto's Github repo: [Support for MacOS](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/335).

You can attempt to [use the macOS development branch](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/335#issuecomment-1242746436) and see if you can get it working for you, but it's apparently still a pretty long way from stable.

> ```
> pip uninstall -y pywinauto
> pip install https://github.com/dariacher/pywinauto/archive/refs/heads/mac_coverage.zip
> ```
>
> Any feedback can be posted here or in PR [#1213](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/pull/1213) which is the most fresh macOS branch.